# Android package naming convention

Tags: java, android, package

Ok so I know the convention is to put com.domainname.applicationname or something along those lines. What if you don't have a website?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the convention is to reduce the chance of name collisions. The idea is that if you own the "custombuggywhips.com" web site, then you are likely going to be the only developer using the package name `com.custombuggywhips`. It also reduces the chance of copyright or trademark problems. Android distinguishes between applications based solely on the application package declared in the manifest, so reducing the chance of collisions is very important.

If you don't own a web site, you can still use the convention for a web site that you might someday own and that would likely not be owned by anyone else. Alternatively, you can break with the convention and use a totally made up package name.

But the best thing would be to reserve a domain name for your development work and go with that. You don't actually need a web site, just a name that you can call your own.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.

Comment: Ok thanks! So if I wanted to use a name that I would want to name my company if I had one one day, I could just use: "mycompanyname.games.myapplicationname"?

Comment: @user3843164 - I'd go with "com.mycompanyname.games.myapplicationname" to stick with the usual conventions. Just make sure your dream company name isn't "Ford" or something like that. :) (However, I'd still suggest actually reserving a name. The cost is pretty minor and it's added insurance that someone else won't claim it.)

Comment: why does it always start with "com". Just curious.

Comment: @Ranjith : It doesn't *always* start with "com". I'm in the UK and I own two domains - my packages start with either "uk.co" or "uk.org" depending on my apps. BAsically it's just a convention using a reverse domain name.

Comment: @TedHopp : **"you can still use the convention for a web site that you might someday own and that would likely not be owned by anyone else"** : Risky - it's difficult to pick a domain name which somebody else is never going to want in the future.

Comment: @Squonk - Agreed. That's why I added the recommendation to just go ahead and reserve a name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't require valid website to decide on package name. You can define any packagename which is unique and relevant to your app.

For example if your company name is "test" then you can have package name as com.example.test

Comment: -1, If your distributing your programs to the wider world,  having a package named `com.android.<anything>` would be a bad idea... why not com.emailprovider.emailusername or the like?

Comment: Not sure, why its Down vote? My answer was just to say that having Website is not mandatory.. You just need to define any package name.

Comment: You're suggesting naming a package under `com.android`.

Comment: My intention was to explain that you don't need to have the website. Also no-one will stop you for making app starting with com.android ........Anyways.. edited it.

Comment: Right, it's much better and I removed my downvote because it's not dangerously wrong. On "no-one will stop you" - Yes, I could name my packages `com.google.foo` or `myprogram.stuff.now`, but it's not what _every other Java programmer_ would expect

Comment: @jdphenix - Not only is it not what other programmers would expect, but I suspect that you would be inviting legal action as the name owners sought to protect their IP rights. (I sure wouldn't want someone else using my domain name in their package, and I would do what I could to stop it if I found out it was happening.)